# Redirect DIR/SubDIR/page.php to /page.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Please see the following URL format:

```
/faq/ANY_SUB_DIRECTORY/SOME_PAGE.php
```

What I want to do is to redirect these kind of URLs to the following using HTACCESS to root:

```
/SOME_PAGE.php
```

I only want to redirect the urls that has `/faq/*/*.php` format to `/*.php`. Is it possible to redirect URL formats like this? I am trying for last few hours but failed completely! Waiting for your valuable suggestions.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^faq/*/(.*)\.php$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^faq/([^/]*)\.php$ faqpreview.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^faq/([^/\.]+)/?$\.php /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^faq/.+/([^/.]+\.php)$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

This will do silent rewrite without changing the URL, if you want to change URL in browser as well then use:

```
RewriteRule ^faq/.+/([^/.]+\.php)$ /$1.php [L,NC,R=302]
```